# Cognito Field Matching

Tags: integration, salesforce-id

I know there is Zapier integration between Cognito forms and Salesforce, however does anyone know if there is a way to do matching between a field on a Cognito form and a field in a Salesforce object to establish if a new record needs to be created within that Salesforce object?
Thanks in advance.